# I want to parse URL with hash # mark and then use it in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to get URL with hash and then pass it to php

I know how to get # value in jQuery

```
<?php 
    $url = $_GET['url']; // its a dynamic url string eg: https://example.com/myfile/#url=someDynamicValue
?>
```

I can get the `someDynamicValue` with jQuery code below

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var url = window.location.hash;
        url = url.replace('#url=','');
    });
</script>
```

But I want to match this `someDynamicValue` in my PHP codes

```
<?php
    $glink = 'http://example.com/datafile.php?hash=someDynamicValue';
    $json = file_get_contents($glink);      
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    $dfile = $data['formats'][0]['file'];
    echo $dfile;
?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may want to look at the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` to get the URL and query paths in PHP. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Hashes are only used in the client, they're not sent to the server. So you can't get it in PHP.

Comment: thanks for the reply @AlJohn but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` is not returning `someDynamicValue` after hash mark

Comment: I know that @Barmar but there must be some work around to achieve this, that's why I'm here

Comment: Have your JavaScript code convert the hash value to a query parameter.

Comment: All the codes I'm using are already posted, I'm good with `PHP` but not good with `jQuery`

Comment: `datafile.php` should use `$_GET['hash']`, not `$_GET['url']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253243/discussion-between-k-mughal-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

You can have URLs of the following form:

- `<somepath>`
- `<somepath>?<someparameters>`

and you may have a hash at the end of either. Here we will have a function that will add the hash to the URL and then you can post it to your server:

```js
function addHashToURL(input) {
    let hashPosition = input.indexOf('#');
    if (hashPosition < 0) return input; //The input does not contain a hash
    let questionPosition = input.indexOf('?'); //We need to know whether the first hash parameter is also the first parameter overall
    let replaceChar = ((questionPosition >= 0) && (questionPosition < hashPosition)) ? '&' : '?';
    let prefix = input.substring(0, hashPosition);
    let suffix = input.substring(hashPosition + 1); //We leave out the hash and replace its value
    return prefix + replaceChar + suffix;
}

console.log(addHashToURL('https://a.b.c'));
console.log(addHashToURL('https://a.b.c#first=1&second=2'));
console.log(addHashToURL('https://a.c.c?param=val'));
console.log(addHashToURL('https://a.c.c?param=val#first=1&second=2'));
```

You can call this function with the URL of your preference.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Lajos Arpad 
If try like this  `finalhash = addHashToURL(window.location.hash);` then how to match this finalhash to php api call `<?php $link = 'http://example.com/datafile.php?hash='.finalhash; ?>`

Comment: @K.Mughal your `addHashToURL(window.location.hash)` only passes the hash to the function you need to pass the URL along with the hash. You need to pass `window.location` instead, as in `addHashToURL(window.location)`. The result will be a URL. You will need to send a request (see https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to your server and, assuming that your URL ended with `#hash=somevalue` and now ends with `?hash=somevalue` or `&hash=somevalue`, you will be able to get the hash value on your server via `$_GET['hash']` or `$_POST['hash']`.

Comment: @K.Mughal please let me know if you are stuck. If this answer led you to a solution, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: I tried your solution but Its changing `#url=DynamicValue` to `?url=DynamicValue` in order to get variable to match php which I don't want, I want the solution for not to changing the `#url=DynamicValue` in the browser and by staying on the current page

Comment: @K.Mughal your server will not see your `url` value if you do not pass to it. Hash values will stay in your browser and will not be sent to the server. That's why I proposed converting your hash into a parameter. It's very important to understand that you will absolutely need to convert your hash into a request parameter to make sure your request will take it into account. Now, I understand that the way you were trying to use this function was not yet working well for you. Can you tell me exactly how you tried to use it?

Comment: I tried this way 
`<script>
$(function(){
 var url = window.location.hash;
 url = url.replace('#url=','');
 window.location = 'test.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
});
</script>`

Comment: @K.Mughal right. You are redirecting the page, which is undesired. You should avoid here `window.location = <something>` and send an AJAX request instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253246/discussion-between-k-mughal-and-lajos-arpad).